# ManyToOne Hibernate автоматическое добавление даннах

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Есть 2 Entity класса
Filials

```
@Entity 
@NamedQuery(name="allFilials", query="SELECT f FROM Filials f")
public class Filials {@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)     
private int id;     
private String name;
private String adress;  
@OneToMany(mappedBy="filials")  private
List<Opers> opers;

public Filials() {      
super();        
stub }
...
```

Opers

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "allOpers", query = "SELECT o FROM Opers o")
public class Opers {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @ManyToOne
    private Filials filials;

    public Opers() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
....
```

в DAO insert делаю

```
@Override
    public void insert(Opers oper) {
        getSession().save(oper);
    }
```

insertOper.jsp

```
<body>
    <sf:form modelAttribute="opers" 
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/insertOper" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><sf:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Surname</td>
                <td><sf:input path="surname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </sf:form>
```

Мне нужно, чтоб когда insert делал, он брал и ID Filial. В JSP при нажатии на ссылке, он переходит на страницу Opers и переносит Filials ID, но при insert-e этот ID не могу вписать в базу. Каким образом могу его вписать?

Comment: При дебаге в строке `getSession().save(oper);` в `oper` есть `filials`?

Comment: при дебаге `filials` есть, но значение `null`. И в базу он как `null `попадает, дальше мне приходится вручную вписывать в базе значение для него и только после этого оно корректно отображается.  В логах 
`Hibernate: insert into Opers (filials_id, name, surname) values (?, ?, ?)`

Comment: По приведенному коду сложно сказать в чем проблема. Для начала можно попробовать указать "не ленивую" инициализацию. `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

Comment: При открытии 1 страницы контроллер добавляет в модель атрибут `oper`, потом по клику идет переход на новую страницу, на которой по клику данные сохраняются в бд? Данные на страницах меняются?

Comment: Опять выходит `null`. Я не знаю каким запросом его вписывать в базу. И откуда он должен брать значение? При переходе на страницу `opers.jsp`,  `filials_id` переходит по URL, но при переходе на страницу `insert.jsp`  `filials_id` не переходит и соответственно ему неоткуда брать значение. Если вам нужны дополнительные фрагменты кода, вы скажите какой фрагмент, я добавлю.

Comment: Сначала открывается страница `filials.jsp`. На этой странице `insert` работает правильно, так как нет связанных таблиц. При клике на какой либо `filial`, он переходит на страницу `opers.jsp`, на которой отображаются оперы по этому филиалу. На странице `opers.jsp`  я перехожу на страницу `insertOper.jsp` и добавляю новых оперов. Они добавляются в общий список оперов и при выводе по филиалам они не выводятся, а выводятся только по `SELECT ALL`

Comment: Выложи код формы из insertOper.jsp

Answer (score 1):

При добавлении объекта, имеющего связь один-ко-многим, не нужно записывать в бд объект, к которому он относится, т.е. записываем `oper`, а не `filial` со всеми операми. 
При отправке формы, в контроллер не передается id филиала. Есть разные варианты, как это можно реализовать.

Самый логичный на мой взгляд:

Страница филиала `http://yoururl/filial/{filialId}`
В контроллере получаем filialId. Создаем новый объект, в который будут записываться данные формы и сразу устанавливаем ему ид филиала.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/filial/{filialId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test(Integer filialId, ModelAndView mav){

        Oper oper= new Oper();
        oper.setFilialId(filialId);
        mav.addObject("oper", oper);
        return mav;
    }
```

Jsp

```
 <sf:form modelAttribute="oper" action="http://yoururl/insertOper" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><sf:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Surname</td>
            <td><sf:input path="surname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</sf:form>
```

Тогда в контроллер `http://yoururl/insertOper` будет приходить `oper` с проставленным филиалом.

Comment: При клике на `filial`, мы переходим на страницу со списком `oper`-ов в этом филиале по ссылке `http://yoururl/opers/{filialId}`. Но в классе `oper` у меня нет `set`-метода 
`Oper oper= new Oper();`
 `oper.setFilialId(filialId);` И вся проблема я думаю в этом, что не могу добавить `filialId` в программе. Только лишь в Workbench в ручную

Comment: Ну так добавь. Конечно сеттер должен быть.

Comment: как добавить сеттер для одного столбца? При инициализации, Hibernate создает объект Filials и в него я должен вписывать объект.

Comment: Обычный сеттер, который может сгенерировать любая IDE. Именование классов у вас сбивает. Почему `Filials`, а не `Filial`?

Comment: Сделайте объект Filial, а множество филиалов представляйте с помощью `List` или `Set`.